# Passing an object array to Fortran using f2py

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Fortran subroutines can take another subroutine as argument.

```
subroutine mst(yht)
 ..
 ..
 call yht(..)
```

But how about an array of objects from python? How can I send say

`arr=[yht,yht,yht]`

to Fortran. I tried it but failed.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps an extended comment rather than an answer ...

As I understand it `f2py` will translate Fortran procedure (ie functions and subroutines) signatures into Python.  I don't think that `f2py` will translate Fortran derived-type definitions into Python object definitions.  I've not used `f2py` for several years so I may be wrong on this. The obvious route, of identifying Python objects with instances of Fortran derived types, may be difficult to implement.

You might have more success if you can persuade your Python code to create things which a Fortran compiler recognises as C structs and use the interoperability-with-C features of Fortran to read and write them.  [Metcalf, Reid and Cohen](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Explained-Numerical-Mathematics-Scientific-Computation/dp/0199601429/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1342000685&sr=1-1) state (p246)

> These restrictions allow the type to interoperate with a C struct type
>   that has the same number of components. The components correspond by
>   position in their definitions. Each Fortran component must be
>   interoperable with the corresponding C component.